# Fslex, binary file lexing

Tags: f#, fslex

Is there any ability to lexemize binary file formats (e.g. jpeg images) with Fslex (with no readability lacks) or i should write my own lexer/use something like fparsec?

Comment: If you can write the lexing rules you can do it

Comment: hi - IMHO you don't need anything as sophisticated as fslex/fsyacc or fsparsec to read in a jpeg file. Those file formats were made to be easily read/write/process by programms, have fixed formats, headers, etc. - it's straight forward to read them in and you sureley don't need generated tokens or abstract syntax trees for them

Comment: I agree with Carsten. You can read about binary parsing here: http://langexplr.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-f-computation-expressions-to-read.html also Don Syme wrote about parser combinators in his Expert F#...

Comment: actually it's not a real task to read jpegs. just interesting

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/devshorts/ParsecClone. It's a parser combinators library supporting binary parsing.